# Android market style tabs

Tags: android

I was wondering if anyone knew how to go about creating functionality like there is in the latest android market place? i.e. short tabs and slide to change view. Is this functionality replacing tabs in design trends for android? I need to make it backwards compatible to 2.1/2.2 really (i.e. if its native in ICS then thats great, but how does the market make it work on earlier androids?)

Thanks guys. Image below for reference. "Tabs" are where it says "Categories", "Featured" and "top paid".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a support package for android to use this type of cool designs, fragments, action bar, etc. for lower versions of Android. You should look at  [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

For design patterns & trends, I always look at these two web sites ;

http://www.iosinspires.me/

http://www.androiduipatterns.com/

Comment: Hi, How did you implement this tab swiping animation? I need to implement it in my current app. Any info is appreciated.

Comment: @leo there is a good tutorial in this link; http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: @aacanakin thanks for replying. I am looking for something different. I want to swipe the tabs itself. User will swipe the tabs. And selected one will always be in middle. And left and right tabs should be half visible to indicate there is more in either side. There used be a menu like this in BlackBerry 5 (horizontal slide) - see http://crackberry.com/sites/crackberry.com/files/u7860/BB7_devices.jpg - text tabs above icons